# SQL script syntax error

Tags: sql, sqlite, syntax-error

I'm using SQLite in my project and I need to write SQL query to retrieve total cost of the customer's order. Here is the query:

```
SELECT SUM(g.cost * og.amount) 
       * (CASE om.include WHEN 0 THEN 0.0  ELSE m.markup_pct / 100) total_cost

FROM goods g JOIN orders_goods og ON g.good_id = og.good_id
    JOIN orders_markups om ON om.order_id = og.order_id
        JOIN markups m ON om.markup_id = m.markup_id 
                 AND om.view_class_id = m.markup_id
WHERE og.order_id = 0;
```

But when I execute the above query on my database via sqlite3 it complains:

```
Error: near line 1: near ")": syntax error
```

Do you have any idea what's wrong with script?

Any help will be appreciated.

**P.S.:** I don't attach database structure because the error is syntactic, so the error is unrelated to the structure of DB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a syntax error in the case statement: it's missing the `END`:

```
(CASE om.include WHEN 0 THEN 0.0  ELSE m.markup_pct / 100 **END**) total_cost
```

Comment: So simple! I'd completely forgot that CASE might need such a delimiter. Thanks for quick answer :)